# get the top 25% intensity value of image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to create a threshold mask equal to the top 25% of the image intensity values. I used this code but does not generate the desired value:

```
img1 = im2double(imread('image1.tif'));
threshold = (0.25);
img1(img1 < threshold) = 0;
img1(img1 > threshold) =1;
```

Comment: I tried, it does! What is the problem? try it for `cameraman` and then `imshow`.

Comment: Also see if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617221/bitwise-color-filter-in-matlab/26617359#26617359

Comment: Did either of the solutions provided here work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`prctile`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/stats/prctile.html?refresh=true)

```
img1 = im2double(imread('image1.tif'));
threshold = prctile(img1(:),75);
img1(img1 <  threshold) = 0;
img1(img1 >= threshold) = 1;
```

Comment: your solution looks legit but i dunno why im not getting the desired image! im sure the desired image is correct with the 25% masking since its from the gonazelz's image processing book!

Comment: @jim Hmm... interesting question, could you provide the image and what you are aiming for? Just if you are motivated enough to clarify the mystery :)

Comment: I think OP might be looking for a `cumsumed` version, I don't know, it's a still a guess work without knowing what he/she expects in terms of 25% intensity thing! +1 for providing a short way to achieve that until OP clarifies on the "correct" way.

Answer (score 2):

Updated version -

```
img1 = im2double(imread('coins.png')); %// input image

threshold = 0.25;
[simg1,sind] = sort(img1(:),'descend');
idx = find(cumsum(simg1(:)) >= sum(img1(:))*threshold ,1,'first');
mask = false(size(img1));
mask(sind(1:idx))= 1;

figure,imshow(img1)
figure,imshow(mask)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess I am stuck... why doesn't you like the percentile version?

Comment: @matheburg Nothing wrong with it! Just sticking to Image Process. toolbox or I guess just providing another way to solve it! :) It makes sense to solve with numerous ways, right? :)

Comment: @matheburg You both have good solutions and it's nice to have two different approaches. +1 all around